# Magento 2 - Update Product stock and Price Programmatically for multiple stores

Tags: magento2, stock, multistore

I'm getting data from the CSV file and according to SKU file load the product.

We are getting 30 products from the CSV file and update those product data in Magento.

We have set up cron every 5 minutes and after 5 minutes it will get the next 30 products and update.

The starting process script is working fine. But after the sometime script is going to be slow and it will take time to update the product.

So, the next cron is running at on the same time there are lots of scripts are running on the server, and the server load will increase.

After taking so much load on the server website going to be slow.

Can you please let me know the way so product updating process will be consistent and time will not so much vary.

public function execute()
{

```
        $data = array of csv file data;
        $sql = "Select value FROM " . $tableName . " where path='catalog/product/update_cron' and scope_id=0";
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        $update_cron = $result[0]['value'];
        $total_products = count($data);
        if ($total_products == $update_cron) {

            $this->configWriter->save('catalog/product/update_cron_status', '1', 'default', '0'); // inject Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
            exit;
        }
        
        if ($update_cron != '' && $update_cron != 0) {
            $data = array_slice($data, (int)$update_cron, 30);
        } else {
            $update_cron = 0;
            $data = array_slice($data, 0, 30);
        }
        $current_date = date("m/d/Y");

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            
            /*********************************************Update Product Price********************************************************/

            if ($value['Artikel'] != '') {

                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                $product_id = $product->getIdBySku($value['Artikel']);
                if (!empty($product_id)) {
                    
                    /************************Update Product Price for all Stores**************************************/

                    $price_b2b = str_replace(',', '.', (string) $value['Verkoopprijs']);
                    $price_b2c = str_replace(',', '.', (string) $value['Numeriek1']);
                    $price_club = str_replace(',', '.', (string) $value['Numeriek2']);
                    //$special_price_b2b = str_replace(',', '.', (string) $value['Numeriek3']);
                    
                    $productActionObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
                    $productActionObject->updateAttributes(array($product_id), 
                        array(
                            'name' => $value['Artikel'],
                            'ean_code'=>$value['Barcode'],
                            'price'=>$price_b2c,
                            'price_wholesale'=>$price_b2b,
                            'price_clubs'=>$price_club,
                            'description'=>$value['Omschrijving Engels'],
                        ),0
                    );
                    
                    /* if ($value['Boolean1'] == 'True') {

                        $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array('price' => $price_b2b, 'special_price' => $special_price_b2b, 'special_from_date' => $current_date), 4);

                    } else { */

                        $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array('price' => $price_b2b, 'special_price' => '', 'special_from_date' => ''), 4);
                    //}
                    
                    $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array('price' => $price_club), 7);

                    /*********************************************Inventory Update********************************************************/
                    $stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
                    $sku = $value['Artikel'];
                    
                    
                    if($sku != '')
                    {
                        $qty = round(str_replace(',', '', (string) $value['Stock']));
                        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
                        $stockItem->setQty($value['Stock']);
                        $stockItem->setIsInStock((int) ($qty > 0)); // this line
                        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
                    }

                    /*****************************************************************************************************/
                }
                
                $i++;

                $update_val = $update_cron + $i;
                
                $this->configWriter->save('catalog/product/update_cron', $update_val, 'default', 0);
            }
            else {

                $i++;

                $update_val = $update_cron + $i;

                $this->configWriter->save('catalog/product/update_cron', $update_val, 'default', 0);
            }
        }
        die('records completed');
    }
    }
    die('stop');
}
```

Thanks in advance